# Метаданные с кириллицей не воспринимаются

Tags: python

Есть код

```
from PIL import  Image
from PIL.ExifTags import  TAGS

imageName='61055535.jpg'
image=Image.open(imageName)

exifData = image.getexif()

for tag_id in exifData:
    tag= TAGS.get(tag_id,tag_id)
    data = exifData.get(tag_id)
    if isinstance(data,bytes):
        data=data.decode()
    print(f'{tag:20} : {data}')
```

В описании фото теги на русском, а этим способом могу вывести только английский. 
В иных случаях ответ:

> ImageDescription     : Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ñ. ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°. Ð¡Ñ‚Ð°Ð´Ð¸Ð¾Ð½ "Ð’Ð­Ð‘ ÐÑ€ÐµÐ½Ð°". > Ð Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸Ð¹ÑÐºÐ°Ñ Ð¿Ñ€ÐµÐ¼ÑŒÐµÑ€-Ð»Ð¸Ð³Ð°. Ð¦Ð¡ÐšÐ (ÐœÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°) - "Ð¡Ð¾Ñ‡Ð¸" > (Ð¡Ð¾Ñ‡Ð¸). ÐœÐ¾Ð¹Ð·ÐµÑ Ð‘Ð°Ñ€Ð±Ð¾Ð·Ð° (Ð¦Ð¡ÐšÐ) Ð¸ ÐšÐ¸Ñ€Ð¸Ð»Ð» ÐšÑ€Ð°Ð²Ñ†Ð¾Ð² ("Ð¡Ð¾Ñ‡Ð¸") Ð²Ð¾ Ð²Ñ€ÐµÐ¼Ñ Ð¼Ð°Ñ‚Ñ‡Ð°. Ð¡ÐµÑ€Ð³ÐµÐ¹ Ð‘Ð¾Ð±Ñ‹Ð»ÐµÐ²/Ð¢ÐÐ¡Ð¡

Comment: Попробуйте указать кодировку в `.decode()`, какую именно - я не знаю, пробуйте типовые `utf-8`, `utf-16-le`, `cp1251`, `cp866`.

Comment: Теоретически еще можно попробовать `utf-8-sig`

Comment: По результату декодирования видно, что исходно там utf-8 (см. диаграмму тут https://habr.com/ru/articles/147843/), этой кодировкой и нужно декодировать.